# Add image map to rotating image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I currently have an Image which rotates 360°. Is there any way so that I can add an imagemap on this. My code is given below

```
  <title>Welcome to Garage</title>
  <body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>Only Available Lamborghini Gallardo's Parts<h1>
  <h2>For 360 View and Order the Parts click on the Pic.<h2> 
  <div id="car_view">      </div>
 </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>  
  <!--3d view script-->
  <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){

  $("#car_view").vc3dEye({
  imagePath:"images/view/",
  totalImages:33,
  imageExtension:"png"
  });
  });
    </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/3deye.min.js"></script>
```

link would be for reference 
http://www.jqueryscript.net/rotator/jQuery-Plugin-For-360-Degree-3D-Panoramic-View-3dEye-js.html

Comment: if doing this with 3d transforms (which `vc3dEye` does afaik because of performance (GPU)) i believe you have to handle clicks in JS and mathematically project them back to what you want to handle